# How to trigger Cloud Function only when child is added to the database?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

How can I modify the code below so that the Function only triggers ***when a child is added***? Currently, the Function is triggered everytime there's a change in the specified reference...

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);



exports.myFunction = functions.database.ref('/messaging/{pushId}')

.onWrite(event => {

//child is added. Do something!

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [onCreate()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events#set_the_event_handler) handler instead of `onWrite()`.

```
exports.myFunction = functions.database.ref('/messaging/{pushId}')

.onCreate(event => {

//child is added. Do something!

});
```